# Debugging Assembly with DDD

Tags: 64-bit, gcc, 32-bit, debugging, assembler

I have a problem when debugging Assembly code with DDD (also tried GDB). When I compile my program and make executable file with `gcc -g -o program program.S` I need to add `-m32` to make 32-bit executable file. But when I open DDD and click "Run" , warnings start to pop-up and after that it looks like program went into inf loop or expects something to be entered from keyboard("Continuing"). I will add two pictures where you can see in bottom left corner what I talked about. 
PS: I am sure that the problem is not in code(the program executes correctly).

[image: Picture with warnings]

After this, it just shows "Continuing" where warnings were.

Comment: Try adding packages that work with with 32bit programs. The topic was addressed before, just google your problem and you'll find the needing line.